# Why am I getting a 404 for a page without the trailing slash but it works with the trailing slash?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I have an app that allows users to create and build a site.  Let's call it *system.com*.  When a user creates a site with a domain (say *domain.com*) they have forwarded to our nameservers, it creates folders and adds their domain to our server through the cPanel API to a folder like *system.com/[user id]/[site id]/*. In that folder there's an index.php file and a .htaccess file that reads:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

I won't go into too much detail about how it works from there, but basically the user can create pages like *domain.com/something/something-else/*.  The "something" folders obviously don't really exist and our system just picks them up from the htaccess and goes from there.

My problem is that *domain.com/something/something-else/* works but *domain.com/something/something-else* returns a 404.  I've been doing research and trying many things but can't seem to get it working.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

**Edit**:

I should have mentioned what I've tried so far.  I've tried changing the rewriterule to work regardless of the trailing slash, like so:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)(?/$) index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

And other variations of that.

I've also tried different methods of forcing a trailing slash but none of those worked either.

Comment: Looks like web-server thinks of `domain.com/something/something-else` as file `something-else` and `something-else/` like folder. Try to remove `/` from your `RewriteRule` like `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]`

Comment: so you mean if the user enter a url without a trailing slash the url rewriter must add a trailing slash automatically?

Comment: Hmm, nope that didn't work either.

Comment: then what is you are trying to do?

Comment: @Mahan well ideally it should pull up the correct page regardless of trailing slash or not, but that's fine if it also does an initial redirect that adds a trailing slash.  I just don't understand why nothing works -- even a standard 301 like `RewriteRule ^something/something-else$ /something/something-else/ [R=301]`

Comment: ok the trick there is to grab your 404 page, grab the URL requested and add a "/" and redirect so it will gonna work

Comment: try to test the stackoverflow pages...

Comment: Sorry but you're not making any sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want your rule to look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Which says : "Any number of any characters optionally followed by a slash should be changed to index.php?page=$1 where $1 is the characters you found before the slash.  Also disregard any other rules that you find if this one matches."

Answer (score 0):

its based on your url rewrite access rule..

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

as you can see **index.php?page=$1** is aliased into **/** and all the requests is sent to index.php

Comment: Right, well that's the behavior that we want and everything works fine when you have a trailing slash.  I added an edit to my original post to show some of the fixes I've tried